# Selecting inner html in a JQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
 <div id="ctl00_m_g_f660033c_e200_4bff_b244_b574efe5b9b5">
    <ul style="margin-left: 0px">
        <li id="li5"><a href="#">T, Paul</a> </li>
        <li id="li4"><a href="#">People**R, Jesse</a> </li>
        <li id="li1"><a href="#">Animals**El Guapo</a> </li>
        <li id="li2"><a href="#">Animals**Sasha</a> </li>
        <li id="li3"><a href="#">People**G, Jenice</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to select only (li) elements that contain ** in the inner text.  I can check for this in JQuery using the following code:

```
 if ($(this).html().indexOf('**') == -1)
   { return; }
```

However, I'd like to do this in the JQuery selector to avoid unnecessary parsing.  I can use something like this to match on the id field:

```
$('ul li a[id*='**']')
```

.. but I wasn't able to find a way to match on the html() within the (a) element in the JQuery selector.  Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [:contains() selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). In this snippet you would write:

```
$("ul li a:contains('**')")
```

Answer (score 12):

You're looking for the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

e.g.

```
$('ul li:contains(**)')
```